# Making mistakes in C in a safer manner?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, stack-overflow

Firstly, I'm a novice.

Secondly, I once ran a C program that tries to modify an OOB array element. I did it in my browser and the website handled the segmentation fault without damaging the environment.

But I'm afraid to do the same thing on my laptop as it might break stuff or corrupt pieces of data.

So, *how can I make these kind of grave mistakes in C without damaging my PC or crying afterwords?*

Any kind of solution will be considered: VM or whatever.

Lastly, thanks.

Comment: On modern desktop environnements an out of bounds access into an array won't damage anything directly on your computer, it may crash the process, but that's basically all. That being said, no, you can't prevent this, C is not a safe language. Read about "undefined behaviour".

Comment: Segmentation faults won't cause any damage.  All they do is cause the offending process to terminate.  Now, it is true that a given bug could, in theory, do all sorts of nasty things, but in practice, they are extremely unlikely to do things that the program isn't already trying to do.  Just make be extra careful when opening a file for writing, or deleting a file, etc. that the file in question is the one you're acting on.  If you do that, you should be pretty safe.

Comment: _Undefined behavior_ may cause damage to data stored _outside_ the program's memory though.

Comment: By doing rigorous error-checking. If you are likely to get an OOB index, then check its range before you use it. Sometimes I make such checks subject to conditional compilation: a debug version.

Comment: ... look into [`assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert), debug builds and debuggers.

Comment: There are no guarantees and it has not only to do with the C language or programming. Make a backup of data that you are afraid to lose.

Comment: So...is "no encounter" the only way to avoid undefined behavior in C? If it is then how do other programmers program in C without breaking their computer? It's confusing...but thanks to you all anyways. 

Answer (score -1):

Do not worry! Modern os protects you! When a segmentation fault happens, it is a signal from the memory management unit, saying: this is not your memory, you are trying to read/write/execute. It will interrupt your program before anything can happen. If you look deeper into how memory works, you will see that nothing can happen, because memory pages of other processes are not mapped to your process. But there is a scary thing. If you write to memory of your process, where you don't want to write, but you are allowed to, weird things will happen. But don't worry, usually they wont do anything are are even detected by your os (stack smashing).

Also if you are using Windows 95 or some other weird thing, you have to be careful, because some old os allow you to write to your text segments (the loaded code).

An exception is the so called kernel space. There anything can happen.

EDIT:
I am not saying it is ok to make your programs crash in a segmentation fault in production. I want to say that it is not harmful for your machine.

Comment: And on an embedded system with no OS? Or with an OS but no memory protection? The protection given by an OS isn't there to relieve you of the need to write robust code. It's a *last resort* to protect the system from a careless programmer.

Comment: Yes of course! But he shouldn't be scary to run his code on his own machine, this ja what I was trying to say. Don't worry I am not trying to encourage people to use it as error handling.

Comment: I'm more worried about what has happened *before* the segmentation fault. Having first overwritten all the memory the program *has* access to may cause all kinds of problems.

Comment: This is the danger of coding in C. But it is impossible to never make mistakes. But like other people pointer out: it is extremly unlikely to break something by accident.

Comment: That also is untrue. It can introduce subtle and hard-to-find bugs that corrupt data locally, and the erroneous data might be stored and reprocessed later before the bug has been discovered. The damage caused might have no obvious connection with the bug.